# Bitcoin implementation with laravel

Tags: laravel, bitcoin

I am new in Laravel. I have to use Bitcoin for checkout page. Can anybody help me how to integrate Bitcoin in laravel framework.

Comment: Accept Bitcoin(Ƀ) and Bitcoin Cash for your business with your Laravel application. Checkout https://github.com/vrajroham/laravel-bitpay

Answer (score 2):

The [Blocktrail PHP SDK](https://github.com/blocktrail/blocktrail-sdk-php/releases/latest) works  with Laravel, in fact there's an example project to get you started: [Simple Block Explorer](https://github.com/blocktrail/simple-block-explorer)

Their API supports payments and webhooks as well as plain blockchain data, check out their API documentation: https://www.blocktrail.com/api/docs

### Update 1

I've added an additional example project - a personal wallet for receiving and making payments (with an integrated block explorer). The project demonstrates the payment api as well as the webhooks api.
See it here: [Simple Bitcoin Wallet App](https://github.com/blocktrail/simple-bitcoin-wallet-app)

Comment: do you have any example for Codignnitor ??

Answer (score -1):

As far as I am aware, there is no library setup for Bitcoin payment processing in Laravel, however the API for Coinbase (https://www.coinbase.com/docs/api/overview) is pretty decent, and shouldn't be too hard to implement yourself.

Answer (score -4):

```
<form action="/create_payment" method="POST">
<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key=pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh
data-image="/square-image.png"
data-name="Demo Site"
data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
data-amount="2000"
data-currency="usd"
data-bitcoin="true">
</script>
</form>
```